# Possible to use ecommerce tracking to track multiple users for a single transaction?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

We're creating a flow for boarding new customers and would like to use the enhanced ecommerce tracking of universal analytics to track the boarding steps.

A single applicant fills in a form supplying information about their business and delivery addresses and such. The problem is that after the application has been submitted, the applicants need to electronically sign an agreement. There can be multiple people signing, and the person signing therefor doesn't necessarily need to be the same person that filled in the application. Is it possible to track a flow where another user/session takes over and finalizes the application?

Comment: This would be almost certainly conflict with Googles Terms of Service which explicitly prohibit to store personally identifiable information, so if you're planning to store adresses etc as part of the transaction that's ano-go.

Comment: Yeah, we're also operating within the financial sector in Sweden so it would probably be illegal as well :S

Comment: @EikePierstorff I'm not sure why it would be necessary to log PII to accomplish this task. It's only required that a new user ID, however that's defined, touches a specific form. This is probably doable with custom dimensions (for both users & forms), though I'm not exactly sure how it might be done.

Comment: @samthebrand, your are right - I have misunderstood the question to mean that they actually want to use GA as backend/data storage for their application process. Seems what the OP is really after is the better funnel visualization that comes with enhanced E-Commerce, so my comment is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If all participants in the application process sign in with a token - same token for all - you can set it as [userID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) and enable session stitching - you'll need special userID view (and update your privacy policy) which will only show visits for which the userID was set and will recognize users across multiple computers, devices etc.

However this will still give you aggregated data only, so if you want to track individual users in addition to the flow you have to set the userID as a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) (talk to your lawyer first, even with an anonymous ID profile building might be a privacy issue). The userID must contain nothing that would allow anybody but your own company to identify a specific user or device (no e-mail-addresses, no MAC addresses etc). Then you can pull the individual data with the custom dimension as key and match it with your CRM data.

No guarantees, but that seems the closest you can get to your requirements using GA.